# Limits of /etc/hosts on Alpine Linux vs Debian

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux, hosts, debian-based

From [https://documents.uow.edu.au/~blane/netapp/ontap/nag/networking/concept/c_oc_netw_maintaining_host_file_limits.html](https://documents.uow.edu.au/%7Eblane/netapp/ontap/nag/networking/concept/c_oc_netw_maintaining_host_file_limits.html) is seems that there are limitations I wasn't aware of. Namely:

- Maximum line size is 256.
- Maximum number of name servers is 3.
- Maximum domain name length is 256.
- Maximum search domains limit is 6. The total number of characters for all search domains cannot exceed 256.
- No file size limit.

In my use case (a GitLab job in Alpine/Debian container with `services` and `kubernetes` executor) I'm interested in **line size limit of 256 chars**.
I found out that to this limit only service aliases (and spaces between them) are counted. E.g. no image names and no localhost IP.

In my testing example (code block below), when I `cat /etc/hosts`, I can see that k8s' `HostAliases` added several hostnames for `127.0.0.1`, repeating (not sure why) service image name (`jamesdbloom-mockserver`) for each one of them.

The whole line is 480 characters long;
without all repetitions of image name it has 264 chars;
and without IP (and its space delimiter) it has 252 chars which makes all hostnames resolvable. If I'd make them longer, the ones that are after the 256 char limit wouldn't be resolvable.

**BUT** this limitation only applies to Alpine. Debian-based images can handle much longer lines/hostnames. My question is **WHY** and **HOW** to make Alpine accept the longer/more hostnames as Debian does.

```
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.194.59.11    runner-pjg8ywgf-project-922-concurrent-0q85mw
# Entries added by HostAliases.
127.0.0.1   jamesdbloom-mockserver  service-123456-mockserver80 jamesdbloom-mockserver  service-123456-mockserver81 jamesdbloom-mockserver  service-123456-mockserver82 jamesdbloom-mockserver  service-123456-mockserver83 jamesdbloom-mockserver  service-123456-mockserver84 jamesdbloom-mockserver  service-123456-mockserver85 jamesdbloom-mockserver  service-123456-mockserver86 jamesdbloom-mockserver  service-123456-mockserver87 jamesdbloom-mockserver  service-123456-mockserver88
```

Comment: DNS resolution happens via the libc implementation. Debian is built with glibc and alpine is built with musl. The doc you linked is for a netapp NAS appliance that's likely based on freebsd, so something else entirely.

Comment: I know that Debian and Alpine differ in the C lib implementation. I didn't know that the link relates to FreeBSD, thanks for that info. Nevertheless the question(s) remains the same as stated in the text.